# event.stopPropagation() Not Ending Bubbling In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting to learn how this bubbling works in Javascript. Now my problem is, I guess I don't understand it completely! I am running an `onclick` in HTML (Which looks like this:

```
onclick="checkboxhit(<?php echo $allmail[$key]["mailid"]; ?>)"
```

), and it is running both the If and Else statements. Basically I am just trying to check **WHEN** and **WHEN NOT** check boxs are clicked. Here is the Javascript I am using:

```
listofmailids = [];
function checkboxhit(mailid) {
    if (listofmailids.indexOf(mailid) == -1) {
        listofmailids.push(mailid);
        $("#deletemail").css("color", "#474747");
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
    else {
        listofmailids.splice(listofmailids.indexOf(mailid), 1);
        if (listofmailids.length == -1) {
            $("#deletemail").css("color", "#A3A3A3");
        }
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
}
```

Yet the `event.stopPropagation()` is not stopping both the If and Else statements from executing. How could I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Where does `event` come from? I wouldn't be surprised if you have console errors

Comment: I don't think you can just put PHP within a string - I think it has to be outside a string and you have to concatenate instead.

Comment: I remember seeing this earlier. I think you need to run `event.preventDefault()` also and return False from the `checkboxhit` function

Comment: Hello @AJK, I tried doing `return false;` after the `propagation`, yet that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @MichaelJones I think you are mixing up JQuery and vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `onclick`, if you want the `event` object, you need to explicitly pass it

```
onclick="checkboxhit(<?= json_encode($allmail[$key]['mailid']) ?>, event)"
```

and in your function

```
function checkboxhit(mailid, e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // etc
```

`json_encode()` will ensure the `$allmail[$key]['mailid']` value is safe for use as a JavaScript literal.

---

If you want to stop propagation *and* prevent the default action, you can use a *falsy* return value like so

```
onclick="return checkboxhit(...)"
```

and in your function

```
return false;
```

Comment: Hello @Phil, thank you for your reply! Now the thing is I am trying `e.stopPropagation();`, yet it is still executing both the `if` and `else`.

Comment: @MichaelJones the bubbling of the event won't effect the logic branches in your function. The only thing that would cause both branches to execute is if your function is run multiple times. Use your browser's debugger to step through the function and see what's triggering it. You can easily place `debugger;` as the first line in your function to start debugging.

Comment: oh my gosh... How could I be so stupid? :( Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

return false is sufficient to stop bubbling as long as there is no JavaScript run-time error prior to reaching the false return.

Explicit passing the event parameter could be done in a more reliable fashion:

```
<a id="test">...</a>
<script>
function checkboxhit(mailid){
  return function(e){
    if (e) e.stopPropagation;
    ...
  }
}
document.getElementById('test').onclick=checkboxhit('123');
</script>
```

The above code runs in IE as well. The chosen answer will cause an error because "e" is not defined.

Comment: What do you mean *"`e` is not defined"*? It's right there, passed in as the second argument to `checkboxhit`

Comment: I see. But if you are manually passing in "event", which is "window.event" for short, you are not using the native, implicit "e" in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using event listeners instead of inline handlers. The `Event` object is added automatically in that case...

Anyway, consider the following - it will behave exactly as you expect :)

```
<div id="outer">
  <button id="test">click me</button>
</div>
```

then...

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation()
}, false)

document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  // never called...
}, false)
```